# Is there a way to turn the results of a SELECT, FROM, GROUPBY statement into a new table?

Tags: sql, ssms, aggregate

Basically I need to put some tables from SQL into Excel to analyze it with a third-party program. However, when using Excel, the PivotTable date columns are in a specific format (d mm) and for the third-party program it will not accept it.

However, in SQL where I have done some aggregations on the raw data, the format that I have used for the aggregation statement is absolutely correct and I would like to turn those results into a separate table so that I can feed it to the external program. I will have an example of what I mean below.

This is the resulting view of what the SQL aggregation statement on the data looks like.

```
    Time             TADCount            TenantId
2019-11-22 00:00:00.000 1   4754F795-2FB9-4647-B28F-2CF2412F0BA2
2019-11-29 00:00:00.000 1   4754F795-2FB9-4647-B28F-2CF2412F0BA2
2019-11-30 00:00:00.000 1   4754F795-2FB9-4647-B28F-2CF2412F0BA2
2019-12-07 00:00:00.000 11  4754F795-2FB9-4647-B28F-2CF2412F0BA2
2019-12-08 00:00:00.000 2   4754F795-2FB9-4647-B28F-2CF2412F0BA2
2019-11-23 00:00:00.000 1   FD85A7E0-BDF5-4A6E-9B69-34AF1A518CB0
2019-11-27 00:00:00.000 1   FD85A7E0-BDF5-4A6E-9B69-34AF1A518CB0
2019-11-28 00:00:00.000 1   FD85A7E0-BDF5-4A6E-9B69-34AF1A518CB0
2019-12-02 00:00:00.000 1   FD85A7E0-BDF5-4A6E-9B69-34AF1A518CB0
2019-12-04 00:00:00.000 1   FD85A7E0-BDF5-4A6E-9B69-34AF1A518CB0
2019-12-06 00:00:00.000 3   FD85A7E0-BDF5-4A6E-9B69-34AF1A518CB0
2019-11-24 00:00:00.000 1   1CB49648-420B-454A-B39D-4DAB361C18B8
2019-11-24 00:00:00.000 5   0E84F35A-D7C1-4BDE-B805-6C7691B9667F
2019-11-26 00:00:00.000 1   0E84F35A-D7C1-4BDE-B805-6C7691B9667F
2019-12-05 00:00:00.000 1   0E84F35A-D7C1-4BDE-B805-6C7691B9667F
2019-12-07 00:00:00.000 2   0E84F35A-D7C1-4BDE-B805-6C7691B9667F
```

For reference, this is the aggregation statement that I have made.

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [Time]), 0) AS Time
  , Count([TenantId]) AS TADCount,
  [TenantId]
FROM [dbo].[acms_data] 
GROUP by DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [Time]), 0),[TenantId]
```

Basically I would like to turn that view above the code statement into a table with exactly those values and headers into a separate table that can be interacted with.

Comment: Curios why do you need a separate table? Use CTE or view and avoid added, needless disk space.

Comment: @Parfait I am new to SQL and I didn't know what to do

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`SELECT INTO` is what you want to use here. Assuming you have the permissions to create a new table the steps would be:

1. Create the table you want to insert the data in
2. Convert the `SELECT` query into a `SELECT INTO` query.

Here's an [example](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) from  W3 Schools I've modified for your use case that should work. The main thing is that the new_table should already be created then modify your select query by adding an `INTO`:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [Time]), 0) AS Time
  , Count([TenantId]) AS TADCount,
  [TenantId]
INTO [dbo].[new_table]
FROM [dbo].[acms_data] 
GROUP by DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [Time]), 0),[TenantId]
```

Comment: `SELECT INTO` fails if the table already exists, so it's either use only `SELECT INTO` OR create the table then use `INSERT INTO...SELECT`.  I'd recommend the latter because you can better control the datatypes and lengths of the columns in the table if you create it yourself.